# Double Widehat X

Tags: math-mode

How can I center double widehats on X? It works well on Y, but the second widehat on the X has a different center.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $\widehat{\widehat{Y}}$ \hspace{1cm}    $\widehat{\widehat{X}}$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is not `amsmath` per se, it shows without it. It is core  `math-mode` issue so probably tag should be edited.

Comment: If you can switch to `unicode-math` (and use lualatex/xelatex), it might be an option, since there it looks better.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know an automated solution, but in the code below I define a macro `\wdoublehat` with optional argument a math glue and `\wdoublehat[1.5mu]{X}` appears to be somewhat satisfactory, as it would be for letter `Z` as well, but for other letters you should adjust the `1.5mu`, and for `Y` not use optional argument.

The screenshot shows that the root cause is the position of the letter inside its bounding box.  The placement (and size) of the external `\widehat` clearly depends on this bounding box (the first `\widehat` seems to know more, perhaps some italic correction thing or other data associated to the glyph that it queries; but the external one appears to use only the bounding box of its (now not a letter) argument).  The problem with `X` is that relative to the mid point of the bounding box the (top) of the letter is far more to the right than is the case with `Y`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    
\makeatletter
\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{{\fboxsep-\fboxrule\fbox{$\x$}} }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{{\fboxsep-\fboxrule\fbox{$\widehat{\x}$}} }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{$\widehat{\hbox{\fboxsep-\fboxrule\fbox{$\widehat{\x}$}}}$ } 
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{$\widehat{\widehat{\x}}$ } 
\makeatother

\newcommand\wdoublehat[2][0mu]{\mskip#1\widehat{\mskip-#1\widehat{#2}\mskip#1}\mskip-#1\relax}

\makeatletter
\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{$\wdoublehat[1.5mu]{\x}$ } 
\makeatother


\end{document}
```

output (the next to last line show nested `\widehat`,  the last line shows using `\wdoublehat` and `1.5mu` shift)

[image: widehat double]

Again:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\wdoublehat[2][0mu]{\mskip#1\widehat{\mskip-#1\widehat{#2}\mskip#1}\mskip-#1\relax}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
$\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{\widehat{\widehat{\x}}}$ (nested, no shift)
\makeatother

\makeatletter
$\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{\wdoublehat[1.5mu]{\x}}$ (1.5mu shift)
\makeatother

\makeatletter
$\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{\wdoublehat[2mu]{\x}}$ (2mu shift)
\makeatother

\makeatletter
$\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{\wdoublehat[2.5mu]{\x}}$ (2.5mu shift)
\makeatother

\makeatletter
$\@tfor\x:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do{\wdoublehat[3mu]{\x}}$ (3mu shift)
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image: more demo]

(there is in this screenshot some ink above left of X on first line which is a Q descender from the full document from which I took screenshot: don't go get a scrub-sponge to clean your screen!)

It is possible to store in an array like structure the per-letter needed shifts and then the usage would be automatic.  But this is better left to user to define in preamble once and for all such `\doublehatX` etc... commands using suitably the `\wdoublehat[<mu shift>]` from this answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "better" to compose a two-level accent, with the two placed directly one above the other, and then applying the composite to the ideal location for a single accent?

Comment: @barbarabeeton nice suggestion! I currently have no idea if you can manage to then let TeX's `\mathaccent` work with that.  I would perhaps need to revisit TeX by Topic and/or some dreaded Appendix G of the TeXBook...

Comment: Obviously it would be easier if doubled accents were in Unicode and/or in fonts.  I seem to remember this being addressed in the days of "plain TeX", and I think one of my TeX friends was involved.  I'll explore.

Comment: Memory worked.  An article in the 1987 TUG proceedigs, in the TeXniques, not TUGboat, at ttps://tug.org/texniques/tn05/tn05complete.pdf on (printed) pages 5-26.  By Christina Thiele, "TeX, Linguistics, and Journal Production".  The relevant concept is the definition of `\diatop`, on p.12.  I haven't compared the code with yours in detail, but it might be worth testing.

Comment: Oops!  There's an omission in that definition.  In the first line, `\def\diatop[#il#2]{{\setbox1=...` there should be a `\leavevmode` before `\setbox1`.  (Correction provided by author, who has a better memory than mine.)

Comment: Thanks! This works great.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I looked at the macro but it text-accent only device.  Substantial rework would be needed here for a `\mathaccent`.  Besides, from my reading of the macro, even the idea it implements does not seem appropriate here: it puts the second accent in a centered position using the width of the accented letter.  In our case this would not give good result due to italic shape.